# Is there away to rename a VM in System Centre Virtual Machine Manager 2012 R2?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a VM in SCVMM that the VM name no longer reflects the name of the OS.  OS had to be renamed, and now the VM in SCVMM name is incorrect, and it's greyed out so I can't rename it. Is there any Powershelgl cmdlets to rename the VM in SCVMM 2012 R2?  Thanks

Comment: You might get better luck asking on our sister site [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) as SCVMM is more of a server management tool than a programming tool. You can flag your question to a moderator and have them move it or you can delete the question here and re-make it there.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about ServerFault!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to set the name of a Virtual Machine managed by SCVMM 2012 R2:

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name "VM03" | Set-SCVirtualMachine -Name "VM04"
```

Cmdlet reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj654500(v=sc.20).aspx